# Non-time-varying covariates in latent growth curve modeling?

Tags: latent-variable, growth-model, lavaan

I know that if I'm doing a latent growth curve model I can use time-varying covariates, i.e. a covariate that has one value for each time point. What if I have a variable that has one value for each case, but not for each time point. Can I still use it as a covariate in a latent growth curve model?

Comment: See this answer from stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106334/time-invariant-predictor-of-slope-and-intercept-in-latent-growth-curve-model-in